# Back button click shows previous page after logout

Tags: jsf-2.2

I am using apache shiro in my web application.I don't want to show previous page after logout, so that I am using dofilter for cache disabling, but it doesn't work.
Below is the code that I have tried.Is something wrong in this? let me know.

**Java code**

```
 import java.io.IOException;
            import javax.servlet.Filter;
            import javax.servlet.FilterChain;
            import javax.servlet.FilterConfig;
            import javax.servlet.ServletException;
            import javax.servlet.ServletRequest;
            import javax.servlet.ServletResponse;
            import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

            public class CacheControlPhaseListener implements Filter {

                @Override
                public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {

         HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) res;
           response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"); 
               response.setHeader("Pragma", "no-cache"); 
                        response.setDateHeader("Expires", 0);                               chain.doFilter(req, res);      

                }

                @Override
                public void destroy() {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                }

                @Override
                public void init(FilterConfig arg0) throws ServletException {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                }
            }
```

**web.xml**

```
<filter> 
    <filter-name>CacheControlPhaseListener</filter-name>
        <filter-class> 
        au.com.bytecode.controller.CacheControlPhaseListener
        </filter-class> 
    </filter>

    <filter-mapping>     
        <filter-name>CacheControlPhaseListener</filter-name>     
        <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>   
    </filter-mapping>

    <filter-mapping>     
        <filter-name>CacheControlPhaseListener</filter-name>     
        <url-pattern>*.jsf</url-pattern>     
    </filter-mapping>



**Shiro ini**
[main]    
    authc.loginUrl = /login.xhtml
    authc.usernameParam = USERNAME
    authc.passwordParam = USERPASSWORD
    authc.rememberMeParam = rememberMe
    user.loginUrl = /login.xhtml

    [users]
    admin=admin
    [urls]
    /login.xhtml = anon
```

Comment: As far as your filter is concerned it is I don't find any mistake in that. It is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

The page that you see is cached at browser level. If you try out to post forms etc then you will get login page. If you dont want browsers to store your page just use

```
<meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate" />
<meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache" />
<meta http-equiv="Expires" content="0" />
```

as first lines after `<html>` tag